# How to select Default option (india) in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, json

country names displaying using select box, select option coming from external json file. Based on selected country i am loading state json file into another select box,till every thing is ok, Now I need set Default selected country as INDIA, I tried bellow code.

### html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
         <select id="country" ng-init="state1 = options['IN']" style="width:250px;" class="" name="selectFranchise" ng-model="state1" ng-change="displayState(state1)">
             <option ng-repeat="(key,country) in countries"  value="{{key}}">{{country[0]}}</option>
          </select>
    </div>{{countries}}{{state1}}    
    <div>
         <select id="state" ng-model="cities">
             <option ng-repeat="(state,city) in states[state1]" value="{{city}}">{{city}}</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.states =  {
     "IN":[
       "Delhi",
       "Goa",
       "Gujarat",
       "Himachal Pradesh",
     ]
   };
   $scope.countries =  {
      IN: ["India"],
       ZA: ["South Africa"],
       AT: ["Austria"]
     }
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc3n55d2/6/)

Comment: you should be using ng-options and not ng-repeat. Also, the ng-model is the selected model (so if you want to have india selected by default make sure it the ng-model).

Comment: country names not coming accending or decending order , how can i do please helpme

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the controller after defining your `$scope.countries`

```
$scope.state1 = Object.keys($scope.countries)[0];
```

Remove `ng-init` from Html page.